# jQuery Cloned Div With Form Fields Not Responding

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select, clone

I'm cloning a div which contains several form fields. I'm doing so to allow a user to upload multiple files and define what class of files they are. The form fields are the following:

```
 <div class="form-inline archivos">
             <div class="form-group">
             <input type="file" name="poder">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <select id="clase" name="clase" class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" tabindex="-1">

                  <option disabled selected> -- Clase -- </option>
                  <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
                  <option value="Penal">Penal</option>
                  <option value="Contencioso-Administrativo">Contencioso Administrativo</option>


              </select>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Renombrar"/>
             </div>
             </div>
```

The thing is, when I have several cloned divs only the first select input works, but none of the cloned ones does...

I use the following jQuery code to do the cloning:

```
    $('#anadir').click(function(){
  $(".archivos:last").clone().insertAfter("div.archivos:last");
});
```

I have tried with name="clase[]" but it's not working either... What do I need to look at to make it work?

Thanks for your time and help!

Southern

Comment: I guess you have events attached to the element and they aren't firing, right? In this case cloning your element like this:   $(".archivos:last").clone(true).insertAfter("div.archivos:last"); should work. By passing true you are cloning also event handlers along with the elements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response matuzo but I already tried using .clone(true) and still not working right... I have noticed that when I click any select dropdown it  highlights the first one. In case that's of any help to isolate the problem :(

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, I can't reproduce it. Do you see the same behavior in this demo (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVzyZw?editors=1010)? If yes, which OS and Browser are you using?

Comment: Damn, yours is working correctly... I'm running Google Chrome under Windows 7. Do you think that the fact that I'm building my site using a template I bought with lots of jquery stuff can be the issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that that's the problem. Either it's maybe even a CSS issue or most probably a JavaScript issue. If you can upload the whole thing, I'll take a look at it, if you want to.

Comment: Mmm, your offer is very generous but this template has an insane number of folders and files, weighing around 80mb... I think I'm just gonna give it up and code my own bootstrap design :( Maybe I'll also write to the template coders and let them know, in case it has a simple fix. I'm very grateful for your help matuzo, I wish you the best!

Comment: BTW, how can I give you reputation?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know honestly ;) Maybe clicking the arrows next to my comments?

Good luck!

Comment: I see no arrows, it's bothering me because I would like to reward you for your time :( I removed the following line from the template and all is working great now :D   `<script src="bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>`